# Running Async Method in Loop without Stackoverflow Exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, windows-8, windows-runtime

This piece of code keeps throwing a `stackoverflow exception` and I have a feeling it's either because of the `await` keyword causing the stack to fill up, or a thread availability issue. However, I'm not sure what the best way of remedying this would be.

The `results` variable is just a collection of `StorageFiles` and if it's above 1020 or so, the exception is thrown; otherwise it's *usually* fine.

```
private async void GetMusicTest()
{
    var sfolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(dir);

    var query =  sfolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

    var results = await query.GetFilesAsync();

    for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
    {
        MusicProperties mp = await results[i].Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine(mp.Title);
    }
}
```

This code works fine in a console application, but the error is thrown when used in a desktop WinForm app.

Interestingly, if `result.Count()` is used instead, then the error is thrown after three iterations, whereas `results.Count` throws it after iterating through at least half of the collection, if not all (it seems to vary). They both return the same values. What's the best way looping through without causing a stackoverflow exception or using up all available threads?

Comment: It seems like there really isn't enough code here.  There's no indication that you're using recursion, or anything else that would take up a lot of space on the stack, so the problem likely includes other sections of code.

Comment: I've updated the code but I didn't think those lines would be particularly relevant. Other than the constructor filling up a few variables, this is the only other method in the class. This is a class instantiated and called from a `Winform`. This person has a similar issue http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/6b84fa0b-f873-43a2-b2ec-e930f95d1d8f

Comment: Why not post the actual exception as well?

Comment: @Soonil - How do I catch an exception from a method that runs on a background thread?

Comment: @keyboardP: What does `GetMusicPropertiesAsync` do? How is `GetMusicTest` called?

Comment: Do you still get the exception if you change the `for` loop to one which just prints out `results[i]`?

Comment: @StephenCleary `GetMusicPropertiesAsync` is from the Windows API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.getmusicpropertiesasync and `GetMusicTest` is called from a WinForm button click event. `myClass A = new myClass; A.GetMusicTest();`

Comment: @JonSkeet - No, the output is `Windows.Storage.StorageFile` for each file and no exception is thrown.

Comment: I tried it out and see the same issue. Actually you can simplify it - just put a for loop (int i = 0; i < 1200; i++) and just invoke the first await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(dir) call within the loop and you get the exception. Must be the way they are chaining the tasks.

Comment: @AndrewS Thanks for confirming, I'm glad I'm not missing something obvious. Was up all night trying to figure it out!

Comment: BTW in order to get a callstack I disabled the vs hosting process and enabled native debugging and then you get stackoverflow like: > ntdll.dll!000007fd404b6473()  
  [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
  ntdll.dll!000007fd404b6426()  
  ntdll.dll!000007fd4059d8db()  
  ntdll.dll!000007fd405baacb()  
  ntdll.dll!000007fd404b6426()  
  combase.dll!000007fd3dca68a9()  
  combase.dll!000007fd3dca66b3()

Comment: With a whole lot of combase.dll calls with the only .net code in there towards the beginning: shell32.dll!000007fd3e5865cf()  
[Managed to Native Transition] 
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AsyncInfoToTaskBridge<Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ImageProperties,System.VoidValueTypeParameter>.Complete(Windows.Foundation.IAsyncInfo asyncInfo, System.Func<Windows.Foundation.IAsyncInfo,Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ImageProperties> getResultsFunction, Windows.Foundation.AsyncStatus asyncStatus) + 0x2b0 bytes 
[Native to Managed Transition] 
shell32.dll!000007fd3e589d16()

Comment: @AndrewS - Thanks. It seems I also have a number of `combase.dll` and `ntdll.dll`as well. Interestingly, near the beginning of the stack, I had this message after the button click event. `The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [think this is a bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/03f49531-7e49-404a-a77f-36edb3069b9c) that should be addressed.

If I'm right, you can work around it by occasionally doing an `await Task.Yield()` within your loop.

Comment: Thanks, that does look like it could be it. I'll leave this thread open for now, but I think it could be a bug.